# Pagination in Jinja2 on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, pagination, jinja2

1. Is there a Pagination function in Jinja2 on Google App Engine?
2. I am thinking about using `from django.core.paginator import Paginator` from django.
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/?from=olddocs

I think I need to include django library in app.yaml:

```
libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.2"
```

But I want to know if this makes my application run slower because I include more libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For pagination is suggested a [query with cursor](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#cursors):

```py
q = ndb.query()
cursor = ndb.Cursor(urlsafe=self.request.get('cursor'))
items, next_curs, more = q.fetch_page(10, start_cursor=cursor) 
if more:
    next_c = next_curs.urlsafe()
else:
    next_c = None
self.generate('home.html', {'items': items, 'cursor': next_c })
```

and in template add a 'more' button

```py
{% if cursor %}
    <a class="btn" href="?cursor={{cursor}}">more..</a>
{% endif %}
```

Is there something similar for the 'old' db.Model